# Computed property from has many returning undefined - Ember

Tags: ember.js

I have a `feed` object which `hasMany` `feedTracks`, each `feedTrack` has a `track` associated with it.

These relationships work successfully, but when I try to use a computed property, something breaks.

on the feed model i have:

```
secondFeedTrack: computed('feedTracks.[]', function() {
  return this.get('feedTracks').then((feedTracks) => {
    return feedTracks.objectAt(1);
  });
})
```

when i do `{{log feed.secondFeedTrack}}` I get:

```
Object { _id: 136, _label: undefined, _state: undefined, _result: undefined, _subscribers: Array[0] }
```

which isn't nothing, but it doesn't look right.

when i do `{{log feed.secondFeedTrack.track}}` i get `undefined`.

What am i doing wrong to not properly get a `feedTrack` from the computed property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that Ember Data returns PromiseObject and PromiseArrays for store methods, but as since you're `.then`ing the promise (async hasMany), it turns into a regular promise.

If you simplify it to:

```
secondFeedTrack: computed('feedTracks.[]', function() {
  return this.get('feedTracks').objectAt(1);
  });
})
```

It should work, as it should update as the relationship resolves.